# Get coordinate based on progress on route - Mapkit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Basically, I have two points, A and B that are 10 miles apart if you drive. I draw a route using driving directions between them using MapKit.

I want to find point C's latitude and longitude, which is at the point on the route 2 miles from point A. This could also work based on a percentage(ex: 20% of the route is completed between point A and B).

[Hopefully, this image can explain better then I can.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXvan.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this using Swift and MapKit?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have a point of coordinates exactly two miles from Point A.

Comment: Have you found any way to do this? I don't understand why the question is marked as unfocused. I've been looking for a solution for this exact issue. I suspect that El Tomato is correct - that there is no method in the code to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the `MKRoute` response you receive from the `MKDirections`.

> An MKRoute object defines the geometry for the route—that is, it contains line segments associated with specific map coordinates.

You will find the documentation for `MKRoute` here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute